# Magic Gap below unordered list in WebLayout

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently i am creating a small website with Twitter Bootstrap. 
I already created a navbar and some contentent below that navbar, so until now my background was white, as was the background of the navbar, so everything was ok.

However, today I changed the background of my body to lighblue(just for the test) and noticed a gap between the navbar and the body. So I searched for hours for some margin i had set, but i couldn´t find any.

Here is a jsfiddle where you can see the white gap which I want to remove.
http://jsfiddle.net/qwm6ku9x/

One ugly workaround is to set the height of the element I gave the id "nav-content" to a hardcoced value.
In this example "`width: 100px !important;`" would work.

However I am interested WHY this gap appears.

I would be very happy if some webguru could explain this behaviour to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `display: inline-block;` is that whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen and there are a few solutions to remove that whitespace in your case. - by [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

**Solution 1:** remove `display: inline-block;` to your `ul` tag. - **[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/qwm6ku9x/3/)**

```
ul {
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

**Solution 2:** apply `display: block;` to your `ul` tag. - **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qwm6ku9x/4/)**

```
ul {
   display: block;
}
```

**Solution 3:** apply `vertical-align: middle;` or `top` or `bottom` to your `ul` tag. - **[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/qwm6ku9x/6/)**

```
ul {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**For more solutions:**

> [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) - by Chris
>   Coyier