# CSS inline issue

Tags: css, inline

I have below code. Weave is

http://liveweave.com/JVtNIk

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quia voluptatem sequi ad iure obcaecati assumenda omnis aperiam ullam cupiditate possimus at ab sint! Dicta quisquam rem sunt aliquid inventore?</div>
<div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quas ipsum minus perspiciatis est quam sit blanditiis harum rem similique eligendi suscipit voluptas ex placeat magnam quos amet! Est ut.</div>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;

}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

Please help me understand the **reason** why the box2 content is not starting from the top but quite from below ? is there any specific reason for that ? I can solve it by adding float but i am just curious on this behavior.

Please someone help me understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may help, apply `vertical-align: top;` to `.box2`, demo - http://liveweave.com/b9dVx5

Comment: Thanks Mary, i wanted to know the reason of this behavior not the solution. thanks anyway

Comment: I dont know enough about the "Why" I'm afraid. But changing the  position to 'absolute' worked for me. Maybe we can narrow it down to the rules surrounding this style property (or the display one).

Comment: @user3751873 I think, this is similar to your's look at my previous answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775383/magic-gap-below-unordered-list-in-weblayout/25775719#25775719

Comment: what i understand is, since box1 is inline, box2 always starts when box1 ends. Like this will be a normal scenario isnt it if i didnt fix the width to 200px. In that case, after the content of box1 finishes, only after that content of box2 starts. Can someone confirm this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this behavior because the baseline of the `.box1` is its last line of text. The `.box2` starts on the same line as this last line so that explain why it is quite at the bottom. Then the `inline` attribute makes it continuing under the `.box1` like if `.box2` was in a `<p>` tag.
Hope you understood my explaination.